# How to cast JQuery to String - or how to avoid the need?

Tags: jquery, typescript, typeahead.js

typeahead.js uses *val* "method" to return the value of the input field:

```
jQuery#typeahead('val')
```

(https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#api)

Unfortunately [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/typeahead/typeahead.d.ts) d.ts for typeahead.sj does not contain the existence of this "method".

But when I try to add the new signature

```
typeahead(methodName : 'val'): string;
```

I get this error

> TS2154: Specialized overload signature is not assignable to any non-specialized signature.

Now if I get it right that is because other methods with different signatures already exist, e.g. this

```
typeahead(methodName: 'destroy'): JQuery;
```

Everything works fine if I create a signature that return the JQuery object

```
typeahead(methodName : 'val'): JQuery;
```

except the "method" now returns JQuery instead of String and when I try to cast it to String like this

```
<string>$('#typeahead').typeahead('val')
```

I get this error

> TS2012: Cannot convert 'JQuery' to 'string':  Type 'String' is missing
>   property 'ajaxComplete' from type 'JQuery'.

**How do I implement the val "method" correctly?**

PS: I keep using apostrophes for the word "method" because I find it ridiculous that in 2014 JQuery plugins use strings as method names.

Comment: Fixed : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/2538

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few rules to follow when using specialized overload signatures:

> • There must be at least one non-specialized signature.
>
> • Each
>   specialized signature must return a sub-type of a non-specialized
>   signature.
>
> • The implementation signature must be compatible with all
>   signatures.

(Source: [Ch1, Pro TypeScript](http://www.apress.com/9781430267911))

So in your case, you don't need to change the specialized overload that you are trying to add; but you do need to add a non-specialized signature for it to be compatible with (i.e. one that returns a string, rather than jQuery):

```
interface JQuery {
    // Non-specialized (but matching) signature
    typeahead(methodName: string): string;

    // Specialized signature
    typeahead(methodName : 'val') : string;
}
```

Comment: btw that's interesting book

Comment: Thanks :) - almost finished too!

Comment: oh! I didn't notice, you are the author :). That's great, I am in total need for experienced/pro level typescript resource. Will I get the full version when I buy the alpha? The FAQ surprisingly does not answer this question http://www.apress.com/customer-support/#alpha-book-info

Comment: Yes - you get early access and then the full final one when it is done.